# Nano opens extremely slow on mac while using ZSH?

Tags: macos, mac, iterm2, nano

Whenever I type try to open a file using nano on my mac while in ZSH, it takes about 4 seconds before nano actually opens and I'm unsure why. Does anyone have suggestions to debug this issue and figure out a fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I didn't get any responses to this I figured I would post my current work around, albeit kinda tacky.

Since the issue only seemed to happen when I was using zsh, I added the following to the end of my `~/.zshrc` file to force nano to always open in bash instead of zsh.

```
# For some reason, when I open nano in zsh it's incredibly slow
# So instead, alias it with this function that forces nano
# to open in bash instead of zsh.
function nano() {
    bash -c "nano $@"
}
```

While this probably isn't the best solution, I have no idea what's going on or how to resolve it. And for the time being, this fixes it.